# PBI Embedded Visuals Won't Stop Moving

Tags: javascript, css, powerbi-embedded

My Power BI Embedded visuals keep moving/resizing, any ideas what's causing this? I've added several tags because I'm not sure where the issue is.

A video of what's happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocCgGsWW7TY&feature=youtu.be

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more details:

1. What is your operating system? iOS?
2. In which view mode you save your report: Fit-To-Page? Fit-To-Width? Actual-Size?
3. Do you use mobile layout?
4. Do you use custom visuals?

Please try to save the report in "Fit-To-Width".